# How to solve this error? session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter

Tags: php, html

Im encountered the above error and strucked up, thinking that for 3 hours. Is there any way to solve this??

Comment: Could you add an example of use?

Answer (score 2):

**You are probably trying to start session after the output has begun.** Starting a session involves setting HTTP headers. Header can be modified *only* before sending any output from PHP script. Some PHP installations have output buffering enabled, so it is actually possible to start outputting content before dealing with sessions - PHP engine will sort it out automatically. Apparently, on your system it's disabled by default. Try setting [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) parameters in `php.ini` or `.htaccess` file. If that doesn't help, review your code and check if there is any HTML, echo/print statements before you call `session_start()`. Also, check for blank characters (new-line character, tab, space) before and after `<?php`  `?>` tags. They all must go. Finally, check your editor settings and make sure that Unicode preambe is turned off.